# exec multiple table-value functions and get merged result without using cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, merge, batch-processing, user-defined-functions

folks. I am working with SQL Server. I have a list called groupIds and a fixed mapping table called group-2-funcs. This mapping table provide transforming from group id into a table-value function. After calling each table-value function a memberIds list be returned. Now, is it possible to get merged member id collection including all member ids from all group ids without using cursor?

groupIds=>funcs=>run all funcs=>multiple memberIds=>merge memberIds into one table

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I would need to see your table layout and sample data. From what you're saying though, you can probably write a union query against the various functions: E.g. `SELECT * FROM func1() UNION SELECT * FROM func2()`.

Comment: I have tree-like organization model. Departments are the roots. Under each department there are multiple sections. People can be directly attached to a department or joint to a section. To complicated, there are some special groups which stand at the same level as departments. A group don't really include any person but just have a related rule(table-function). People mockingly belong to a group will be generated by the rule. 
I have created a JavaScript client which posts back hybrid id array of department, section, group and person. I need work out just one collection of unique person id.

Comment: The union query above should do what you want as far as the groups are concerned. You'll likely need to create a dynamic sql string in order to use it though.

Comment: Good, dynamic sql string using union is a viable method. I'll try to implement it.Thanks.